# How to show OpenCV VideoCapture in Jupyter Labs

Tags: jupyter-lab, opencv, python

I'm trying to show (and process) a webcam stream in Jupyter Lab.

This runs standalone and works as expected:

```py
import cv2

video_url = 'http://some_local_machine/stream/video.mjpeg'
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_url)

is_success = True
l = 100
is_success, frame = cap.read()
while is_success and l > 0:
    is_success, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    l = l-1
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
```

However, when I try to do the same thing in Jupyter Labs, the image is not updated:

```py
import cv2
video_url = 'http://some_local_machine/stream/video.mjpeg'
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_url)

is_success = True
l = 100
is_success, frame = cap.read()
f = plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.show()

while is_success and l > 0:
    is_success, frame = cap.read()
    f.set_data(cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    l = l-1
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
```

I'm not able to use cv2.imshow in JupyterLab. From what I have found, the above is the suggested solution.

I have figured out that the "waitKey" call is somehow important. Even though I don't need the actual key, it seems to be the only way to advance the stream.

I haven't really found a satisfying explanation on why that waitKey call is needed, so I think this may be the issue. However, I'm stuck and can't really figure out what to try next.

One more thing: if I call cap.read() twice in the notebook, I get the same image... Again, this seems to point in the direction that the stream is not "advancing" but, again, I can't seem to find much info on this.

Other things I've tried is ipywebrtc, but this library does not seem to work with the latest JupyterLab.